# how should i do this trigger?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, trigger, insert, update

I am a newbie to the sql world :)
Right now i'm trying to create my first mysql trigger that would either update a row or insert a new one. Could you help me with that ?

Here is the code :

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_vote_question_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON vote_question
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF ((SELECT question_total_mixed FROM vote_total_question WHERE question_id = NEW.question_id) > 0) AND NEW.vote_question_type = '1')
THEN UPDATE vote_total_question
SET question_total_plus = question_total_plus + 1
SET question_total_mixed = question total_mixed + 1
WHERE question_id = NEW.question_id
ELSEIF ((SELECT question_total_mixed FROM vote_total_question WHERE question_id = NEW.question_id) > 0) AND NEW.vote_question_type = '-1')
THEN UPDATE vote_total_question
SET question_total_plus = question_total_plus - 1
SET question_total_mixed = question total_mixed + 1
WHERE question_id = NEW.question_id
ELSEIF ((SELECT question_total_mixed FROM vote_total_question WHERE question_id = NEW.question_id) = NULL) AND NEW.vote_question_type = '1')
THEN INSERT INTO vote_total_question (question_id, question_total_plus, question_total_minus, question_total_mixed) VALUES (NEW.question_id, 1, 0, 1)
ELSEIF ((SELECT question_total_mixed FROM vote_total_question WHERE question_id = NEW.question_id) = NULL) AND NEW.vote_question_type = '-1')
THEN INSERT INTO vote_total_question (question_id, question_total_plus, question_total_minus, question_total_mixed) VALUES (NEW.question_id, 0, 1, 1)
ENDIF
END//
```

Also i might try this trigger with postgresql should i change something ? (ELSEIF to ELSE IF I guess)

Comment: What functional requirements are you trying to solve with this trigger? Why can't you solve this in a declarative fashion?

Comment: I could but wouldn't it be nicer with an automatic trigger ? (plus that way I'm learning new things)
I want the table vote_total_question to be automatically filled with the total number of vote+ and vote- so I don't have to run a count each time.

Comment: Why don't you want to run a count each time?  Is it due to performance -- such as expecting millions of records?  Or you just want it to look like a nice clean table without having to code a count query each time?

Comment: both ? :) performance mainly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would really advise to not have a separate "totals" table that you have to maintain. There would be many downsides to doing so:

- under high volume, you might get transactional locks
- it's possible that your totals get "out of sync" with the source table. If/when this happens, you'd have to take an outage or block insertion of new votes while you're trying to get the totals correct.

Anyhow, I believe you can get a high-performance, real-time vote totals with simple code, without storing separately any totals information and therefore without needing a trigger. You also won't have to worry about any INSERT vs. UPDATE logic.

Make sure your `vote_question` table has an index (nonunique) on the `question_id` column. This will ensure performance for real-time.

Here's a totals query (all questions, summarized):

```
SELECT question_id
   , SUM((vote_question_type)='1') question_total_plus
   , SUM((vote_question_type)='-1') question_total_minus
   , count(*) question_total_mixed
FROM vote_question
GROUP BY question_id;
```

If you don't want to have to put that code in the application side, then no problem, just create it as a database view:

```
CREATE VIEW vote_question_totals
  AS
SELECT question_id
   , SUM((vote_question_type)='1') question_total_plus
   , SUM((vote_question_type)='-1') question_total_minus
   , count(*) question_total_mixed
FROM vote_question
GROUP BY question_id;
```

Then from your application/client side, you can reference the view just as though it were a table (and provide a `question_id`).

```
SELECT question_id, question_total_plus, question_total_minus, question_total_mixed
  FROM vote_question_totals
  WHERE question_id = '???' ;
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this great answer :) I wanted to know what was wrong whit my sql but anyway this is great :)

Comment: note, I'm using the trick in MySQL to implicitly cast `boolean` as `int` (e.g. `vote_question_type='1'` will evaluate to {1,0} when {T,F}). Other RDBMS, including PostgreSQL don't do this as cleanly, so you would have to use a more ANSI SQL compliant version, such as `CASE` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

```
IF ((SELECT question_total_mixed 
     FROM vote_total_question 
     WHERE question_id = NEW.question_id) > 0
    ) AND NEW.vote_question_type in ('1', '-1') 
THEN 
    UPDATE vote_total_question
        SET question_total_plus = question_total_plus + cast(NEW.vote_question_type as int)
          , question_total_mixed = question total_mixed + 1
    WHERE question_id = NEW.question_id

ELSE IF ...
```

Comment: I tried the above with an ENDIF and I got an error near line 7